# storing arrays of string literals without size - std::initializer_lists

Tags: c++, c++20, lifetime, literals

I am exploring methods for storing arrays of literals (any type) without sidecar size information. I've sketched some approaches but for each have some lingering questions. Here I use `std::initializer_list` rather than templating over `std::array`. Please note that this is a simple test case and that actual classes might have additional members, additional template parameters, and template parameters that must be provided.

```
struct B {
    std::initializer_list<const char*> a;
    int b;
};

// Helper for the question
constexpr std::initializer_list<const char*> get1() {
    // Confirm: string literals, lifespan OK?
    return {"1", "2", "3"};
}
```

Since I'm dealing with literal values (stored in the code), why not use an initializer list object rather than templating over an `std::array`? While the list won't have ownership of its contents, as literal values they'll never go out-of-scope. Furthermore the list size need not be specified - regardless of size, no template is required. The only problem is the lack of a subscript operator, leading to slightly more verbose code. The brilliant idea of using initialization lists came from IRC. Look at all the neat things I can do:

```
auto b = B{{"1","2","3"}};
auto b = B{get1()};

std::cout << b.a.begin()[2] << ", size: " << b.a.size() << std::endl;

for (auto& e: b.a) { std::cout << e << std::endl; }

auto l = [](const char* s) { return !strcmp(s, "2"); };
auto r = std::find_if(begin(b.a), end(b.a), l);
std::cout << "result: " << *r << std::endl;
```

Is the underlying storage of the initialization list the string literals? Since string literals are global, will the initialization list be valid for the duration of the program? See the following examples. Am I at risk of dangling pointers? If not, how do I silence the warning?

```
auto b = B{{"1","2","3"}};
auto b = B{get1()};
```

Comment: "*I am exploring methods for storing arrays of literals (any type) without sidecar size information.*" Why is that a thing you want to do? Unsized arrays aren't a good thing.

Comment: The information is still there, just provided by the compiler rather than the user.

Comment: So what this *really* is is that you want to create an `auto`-deduced variable from an expression including a braced-init-list of strings, without explicitly specifying in that expression what the size of that list is. That is, you want `auto lit_list = something{"lit1", "lit2", "lit3"}`, where `something` doesn't specify 3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what it is that you're trying to accomplish with this series of questions. You seem to want to be able to type something along the lines of:

```
TypeId var_name = Syntax{<list of literals>};
```

With the restrictions that:

1. The number of elements in `<list of literals>` should not be written into `TypeId` or `Syntax`. It should be deduced from context.
2. `var_name` should be able to access the literals via array syntax.
3. You should be able to pass around and return `var_name` like any other variable without worrying about ownership of the array it references/contains.

All of your suggestions are flawed with respect to some of these.

`initializer_list` fails #3 because it is backed by a temporary array (you can use it, but you have to be very careful about how you pass them around). `span` is non-workable for similar reasons. `std::array` fails because string literals are not actually `char const*`s, so you have to explicitly say `std::array<char const*>`. But CTAD cannot work if any template parameter is specified.

That last one is the key to the solution: you need a type like `std::array` but one *specifically* for `char const*`. That way, you don't have to provide template parameters, so CTAD can work.

The easiest way to do that is to make a simple type that inherits from `std::array` and give it a deduction guide that counts the number of elements you initialize it with. C++17 allowed aggregates to have base classes, and aggregate initialization's brace elision keeps you from having to use multiple braces:

```
template<std::size_t sz>
struct str_array : std::array<char const*, sz>{};

template<typename ...Ts>
str_array(Ts...) -> str_array<sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was backed by a temporary array. First, is the lifespan of the temporary array tied to the bracketed initialization list, or the `std::initializer_list`? Is this akin to a reference of a temporary array created in the constructor? So in `B{{"1","2","3"}}`, I assume the lifespan of the temporary array is tied to the scope of `B` and if `B` and its members are copied into a new scope the array reference is invalidated. Except unless the copy constructor calls the constructor of the initializer list, but then only once? Does this apply to aggregative initialization?

Comment: The same applies to `B{get1()}`, but is the initializer list created in the calling scope or the caller's scope? I'm trying to understand the 'cppreference' documentation.

Comment: For the record I do appreciate that you tried to understand my motivations - that's a new idea I hadn't thought of and seems pretty neat. I'll give it a shot.